# Dafny: Assertion fails on subset checks

Tags: dafny

Currently, I'm trying to implement an AVL-Tree in Dafny.
Each subnode and the node itself is part of the nodes Repr:set.
After each change in the tree, an update method gets called to update the Repr set.

1. The first assert shows that new_node is not part of the Repr set of
   the left node.
2. The second assert shows that this condition is still correct after
   I assigned the Repr set of the left subnet to the node.
3. The third assert **fails** after I added the node to the Repr set.

I don't understand why the last assert fails, as the set which is checked has not been altered.

```
if(new_node.left != null && new_node.right == null) {
    assert new_node !in new_node.left.Repr;
    new_node.Repr := new_node.left.Repr;
    assert new_node !in new_node.left.Repr;
    new_node.Repr := new_node.Repr + {new_node};
    assert new_node !in new_node.left.Repr;            
    new_node.Contents := {new_node.data} + new_node.left.Contents; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third assertion does not hold if `new_node == new_node.left`. Have you excluded that possibility?